# Obtaining client address with Ruby SSLSockets

Tags: ruby, ssl, tcpsocket

I am playing with TCPSockets today and was using

```
@client_port, @client_addr = Socket.unpack_sockaddr_in(@socket.getpeername)
```

to get the client ip address and port. I've just proceeded to add SSL to the client and server but that now means

```
@socket.getpeername
```

is unsupported (as mentioned in https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8126). Is there another method I can use to get this information? I've googled around for a while but haven't been able to find anything of use.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered from *rubysrc/sample/openssl/echo-svr.rb* that

```
@socket.peeraddr
```

is available to SSLSocket and provides all the required information.